# PyQt - Program to close window with model and view

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt5

Can anyone help me make a good code write and help me to understand the SIGNAL and SLOT with Model and View.
With easy examples and codes i am new in Python and Qt5 and i try to learn in easy way.
I have books with me to learn faster but books do it more complicated to learn and don't do it step by step.

Thank you.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtW
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtC


class Model(qtW.QWidget, qtC.QObject):
    quit = qtC.pyqtSignal(bool)

    message_quit = "GOODBYE !"

    def exit_window(self):
        print(self.message_quit)
        self.quit.emit(self.close())
        
class View(qtW.QWidget):

    message = "Tape Text Here !"
    message_show = "Your message shown here !"
    button_show = "SHOW"
    button_quit = "QUIT"
    message_quit = "GOODBYE !"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid = qtW.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.message_lineEdit = qtW.QLineEdit(self.message)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.message_lineEdit, 0, 0)

        self.message_label = qtW.QLabel(self.message_show)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.message_label, 1, 0)

        self.quit_button = qtW.QPushButton(self.button_quit)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.quit_button, 2, 0)

class MainWindow(qtW.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.view = View()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        self.model = Model()

        self.view.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.model.exit_window)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtW.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Your question is too vague, and I don't see any reference to model and views in your code. Please clarify what you don't understand and what you want to do. Also please take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to close a program with my emit function (exit_window).

Answer (score 0):

The signal / `pyqtSignal()` must be created at the origin, in this case in `View()` and not in `Model()`. Just like the issue / `emit()`, it must also be put at the origin.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtW
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtC


class Model(qtW.QWidget, qtC.QObject):
    #quit = qtC.pyqtSignal(bool)
    message_quit = "GOODBYE !"

    def exit_window(self, bool):
        print(self.message_quit)
        #self.quit.emit(self.close())

            
class View(qtW.QWidget):
    signEmit1 = qtC.pyqtSignal(bool)

    message = "Tape Text Here !"
    message_show = "Your message shown here !"
    button_show = "SHOW"
    button_quit = "QUIT"
    message_quit = "GOODBYE !"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid = qtW.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.message_lineEdit = qtW.QLineEdit(self.message)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.message_lineEdit, 0, 0)
        self.message_label = qtW.QLabel(self.message_show)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.message_label, 1, 0)
        self.quit_button = qtW.QPushButton(self.button_quit)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.quit_button, 2, 0)
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.btnAction)

    def btnAction(self):
        self.signEmit1.emit(True)


class MainWindow(qtW.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View()
        self.view.signEmit1.connect(self.model.exit_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
         self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtW.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Hope this helps